# What is the name for the term/principle that trade causes a net increase in utility

Tags: utility

Pretend that I grow and sell apples and that you are a hungry person.  At that point of time, having an apple is more useful to you than having money.  Because you are hungry and can’t eat money.  However, to me having money would be more useful to me because I have more apples than I could ever use myself.  After you buy the apple from me we are both better off.

This seems to be to be a basic economic principle but because I can describe the idea but don't have its name I don't know what to search for to read up more about that idea.

Comment: Hi! It is not quite clear what you are asking. Are you looking for the term "win-win"? Are you looking for references that discuss the circumstances under which international free trade results in aggregate welfare increase for the countries involved? Something else perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term ["gains from trade"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gains_from_trade) is most commonly used for this.